# Show that the equation has at most two real roots, using the mean value theorem.

Tags: calculus

Show that $x^4 + 4x +c = 0$ has at most two real roots.
Can someone please help me see how I should go about answering this question?

Answer (score 3):

If there are more than 2 real roots, there will be more than 1 points such that $f^\prime(x)=0$, because by mean value theorem there exists one point with zero derivative between two roots.

But
$$f^\prime(x)=4x^3+4=0$$
only at $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = x^4+4x+c$. Then $f'(x) = 4x^3+4$.  Note that $f'(x) = 0$ when

$$x^3+1 = 0 \Rightarrow (x+1)(x^2-x+1)=0.$$

The quadratic term has no real roots (for example, can be seen by checking the determinant), so $f$ has only one critical point at $x=-1.$

Now, note that between consecutive roots, $f$ necessarily must a critical point (by the mean value theorem).  If $f$ had more than two roots then $f$ would have more than two critical points, which is not true, so $f$ must have at most two roots.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question, Do I need to constrain the function and then verify that it is continuous and differentiable within [a,b]?

Comment: I see no reason to constrain the function. Polynomials are differentiable (and thus continuous) on the entire real line so you should have no problem.